# Segmentation fault checking month

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to add code to check if the month 
input on the command line is in the range 1 to 12.
If it is not then print out the following error message and exit the program
(Make sure that your return code is non-zero.)

```
$ ./dates 1 13 2019
Error -the month entered (13) is not in the proper range (1-12)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   /* Names of the months */
   char *monthName[12] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
   /* The number of days in each month */
   int monthLength[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
   int dd = 0;
   int mm = 0;
   int yyyy = 0;
   if ( argc < 4 ) {
      printf ( "Usage: ./dates mm dd yyyy \n" );
      exit ( 1 );
   } else {
      dd = atoi ( argv[1] );
      mm = atoi ( argv[2] );
      yyyy = atoi ( argv[3] );
   }
   if (1<=mm<=12) {
      printf ( "The date is %s %02d, %04d\n", monthName[mm-1], mm, yyyy);
   } else {
      printf ("Error - the month enteres (%d) is not in the proper range ( 1-12)", mm);
   }
   return (1) ;
}
```

Comment: I am a little rusty with C but this appears to not work (1<=mm<=12), but does compile ;)

Comment: `if (1<=mm<=12)` is equivalent to `if ((1 <= mm) <= 12)`. That will always be true because `1 <= mm` is either `0` or `1`.

Comment: `Usage: ./dates mm dd yyyy` is wrong, you switched `mm` and `dd`

Comment: Also note `atoi` provides **zero** error checking capability. Better to use `strtol` and validate the converison.

Comment: I think it should be `printf ( "The date is %s %02d, %04d\n", monthName[mm-1], dd, yyyy);`

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
if (1<=mm<=12) {
.....
```

the expression `1<=mm<=12` will be interpreted as `(1<=mm)<=12` because the associativity of operator `<=` is `left to right`. The result of `1<=mm` will be boolean i.e. either `true` or `false`. Which means it will be evaluated as either `1` or `0`. When `1` or `0` is compared with `12` using operator `<=` the result is always going to be true i.e. `1`. So, the expression `1<=mm<=12` always be evaluated as `true`. If you input the month beyond the range of `monthName` array, the behavior is undefined <sup>1)</sup> because your program will end up accessing the array `monthName` beyond its range. Instead, you should check month like this

```
if ((1 <= mm) && (mm <= 12)) {
......
```

More readable code would be

```
if ((mm >= 1) && (mm <= 12)) {
......
```

---

1) An undefined behavior includes program may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Comment: thanks a lot! that does make sense, but what if I wanted to  add code to check if the day input on the command line is in the range 1 to the number of days in the month. If it is not then print out the following  error message and exit the program.
./dates 31 4 2019 
Error - you entered 31 for the day and that is not in the range 
(1 - 30), what should I do ?

Comment: @HareerThaer For checking the day range, you can modify the condition like this - `if (((mm >= 1) && (mm <= 12)) && ((dd >= 1) && (dd <= monthLength[mm - 1])))`. This will check the day range for that particular month entered by the user. Also, you have to do additional error handling for the case like month is in range but day is not etc. One more point - correct the usage output, it should be - `./dates dd mm yyyy` as in  your program you are considering `argv[2]` as month and `argv[1]` as day.

Answer (score 0):

see @H.S. Answer for why the statement is invalid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

/* Names of the months */ char *monthName[12] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

/* The number of days in each month */ int monthLength[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

int dd = 0;

int mm = 0;

int yyyy = 0;

if ( argc < 4 ) {

  printf ( "Usage: ./dates mm dd yyyy \n" );

  exit ( 1 );
}

dd = atoi ( argv[1] );

mm = atoi ( argv[2] );

yyyy = atoi ( argv[3] );


if ((mm >= 1 && mm <= 12) && (dd <= 31 && dd >= 1)) {

printf ( "The date is %s %02d, %04d\n", monthName[mm-1], mm, yyyy);

} else {

printf ("Error - the month enteres (%d) is not in the proper range ( 1-12)", mm); }

return (1) ; }
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: `(1<=mm<=12)` appears compilable but does not actually work with the c language, I changed your conditional to include a comparison for each value seperately using `&&`

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: I would rather find out why it is compilable and then modify my answer, any hints? @barmar

Comment: It should be obvious, it's operator precedence. See my comment above.

Comment: Someone else already post it as a full answer.